# Issue with respect to Snowflake Clones

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to clone a subset of the source object in Snowflake?
For example I have a table with 100 records and I want to clone only 50 of them using a query. Is this possible with Snowflake Clones?

Comment: I believe the question here is if one can designate which objects to clone from an entire set. If so, then no, one cannot specify or select a subset from the table but if these items are loaded during different times, then based on that one can do it using AT|BEFORE parameters as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html#cloning-using-time-travel-databases-schemas-tables-and-streams-only

Answer (score 0):

Cloning also referred to as “zero-copy cloning” creates a copy of a database, schema or table. A snapshot of data present in the source object is taken when the clone is created and is made available to the cloned object.

You can clone only a subset of the source object using AT | BEFORE clause if you know the timestamp when the records were inserted or statement ID used for inserting the data.

It depends on how the data got inserted/loaded. If the whole 100 records got inserted using a single insert, then it is not possible.Else,if it got loaded with multiple insert statements at different timestamps, then it is possible with AT | BEFORE clause

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/at-before.html#at-before